# Spring batch, Unit test, JPA Transaction and Hibernate Lazy loading : IllegalTransactionStateException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch, transactionmanager

Hy guys,

I want to run a spring batch job and then make some test on the data that result, but I need to use the hibernate lazy loading. So I need an opened transaction to keep the session alive.

But I get this exception : IllegalTransactionStateException : Pre-bound JDBC Connection found!

I could write methods to get directly the associated objects I want to test, but I don't want to write method only for test and to loose hibernate's advantages.

Is there a way to do this ? I've try to set the validateStateTransaction to false in the jobRepositoy but it doesn"t work (in fact it only work with a in memory meta data repository like MapJobRepository).

I'm searching for a couple of days but nothing that works.

Could you help me please ? Thanks

My code here :

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="databaseType">
        <value>POSTGRES</value>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="databasePool" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT" />
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="#{ schema }.BATCH_" />
    <property name="validateTransactionState" value="false" />
</bean>
```

and

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void test() {

    /*
     * ===================RUN JOB======================
     */
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder();

    int returnCode = runJob("job_name", jobParameters);
    assertEquals("returnCode must be 0.", 0, returnCode );

    /*
     * ===============END JOB=============================
     */

    /*
     * ===============TEST ON DATA==========================
     */
    ObjectToTest obj = objectDao.findById("1");

    assertNotNull( obj.getSomeCollection().get(1));

    /*
     * =================END TEST==================
     */

}
```

Here is the exception :

```
org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! JpaTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single JpaTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether JPA or JDBC access.
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:359)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:438)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:261)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:98)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:362)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:590)
at fr.insee.harmonica.commun.batch.CommandLineJobRunnerTest.runJob(CommandLineJobRunnerTest.java:143)
at fr.insee.harmonica.commun.batch.CommandLineJobRunnerTest.execute(CommandLineJobRunnerTest.java:420)
```

I've try to put the test part in another method that would be anotated with @Transactional, but then I get a LazyInitializationException...

**EDIT :**

I use the org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager implementation for transaction Manager.

Here is my spring configuration :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean> 

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

I have searched the way to manually open transaction but I didn't find it yet

Comment: The short answer is that `@Transactional` and Spring Batch don't play nice together since Spring Batch manually handles transactions.  That being said, you haven't posted your transaction manager configuration and the Exception clearly points out to use the `JpaTransactionManager`.  Are you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edit my message in the next minute

Comment: Has somebody a solution ?

Comment: And what happens when you remove the `@Transactional`?

Comment: I get a LazyInitializationException because there is no session open and so the lazy loading doesn't work

Comment: Anybody to help me, cause I think this problem will concern other people one day

Comment: Please provide your full configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution (without any help finally).

To do this you have to open manually a transaction AFTER your job ends.

You can do something like that :

```
@Autowired
protected PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

@Test
public void test() {

/*
 * ===================RUN JOB======================
 */
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder();

int returnCode = runJob("job_name", jobParameters);
assertEquals("returnCode must be 0.", 0, returnCode );

/*
 * ===============END JOB=============================
 */

/*
 * ===============TEST ON DATA==========================
 */
(new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager)).execute(new TransactionCallback() {
        @Override
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {

          ObjectToTest obj = objectDao.findById("1");

          assertNotNull( obj.getSomeCollection().get(1));
 }
});

/*
 * =================END TEST==================
 */




}
```